# Terminology: source and target

Tags: terminology

How should one choose between the words "source" and "target"?

This video processing plugin from Sony Vegas tries to match the color of one video to the color of another. It got me confused because I thought source would be the material that gets processed, and target is something ideal you aim for, but the opposite is the case here.

Adobe Photoshop uses the same convention as Sony Vegas, so it seems wide-spread.

[image: Sony Color Match]

Comment: Well, it's all a matter of viewpoint. 'Source' can also be where you take your data from (the colors), and 'target' is where you apply those colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Olli Niemitalo: I think your notions of the meanings of the words "source" and "target" are compatible with Matt L.'s viewpoint. I agree with you, the video processing plugin's terminology seems backwards.

Comment: Matt's comment explains why they have it backwards, but I do dislike the use of "target" when it refers to "target of processing".